# When using Context3DVertexBufferFormat.BYTES_4, what is the value range of one field?

Tags: flash, arrays, vertex-shader, vertex-buffer, stage3d

If I populate a vertex-buffer by using the byte-array method:

```
//Example:
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

//Write vertex #0:
ba.writeFloat(-.5);
ba.writeFloat(-.5);
ba.writeUnsignedInt(0);
ba.writeUnsignedInt(0);

//Write vertex #1:
ba.writeFloat(.5);
ba.writeFloat(-.5);
ba.writeUnsignedInt(1);
ba.writeUnsignedInt(0);

//Write vertex #2:
ba.writeFloat(.5);
ba.writeFloat(.5);
ba.writeUnsignedInt(1);
ba.writeUnsignedInt(1);

//Write vertex #3:
ba.writeFloat(-.5);
ba.writeFloat(.5);
ba.writeUnsignedInt(0);
ba.writeUnsignedInt(1);

myVertexBuffer.uploadFromByteArray(ba, 0, 0, 4);
```

And then set the vertex-buffer attribute with the following format:

```
var format:String = Context3DVertexBufferFormat.BYTES_4;
context3D.setVertexBufferAt(0, myVertexBuffer, 0, format);
```

What is the range of values possible (0 to 255? 0.0 to 1.0? etc.) for the Vertex attribute's field (in this case, **va0.x, va0.y, va0.z, va0.w**)? Does it vary between which data-type is written to the `ByteArray` object (**writeFloat** vs. **writeUnsignedInt**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BYTES_4 is unpacked as 4 bytes in the [0..1] range. 
So bytes 0xff, 0x7f, 0, 1 would become 1.0, .5, 0, 1/255 in the vertex program.
In you case the WriteUnsignedInt would only populate x with the 1. 
You should use WriteByte 4 times instead, or even better pack your 4 values into one unsigned int, like a color.